# pandas resize excel sheet to match larger one for comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel sheets I need to compare. One of them might have a larger number of rows/columns, therefore in comparison I need to enlarge the smaller dataframe (and possibly fill the surplus with NaNs?) to make the compare possible.

larger dataframe:
[image]

smaller dataframe:
[image]

dataframe I need to use for comparison against smaller dataframe:
[image]

Code attached below. I'm basically iterating through two folders, checking for the pairs of files with the same name so then I can compare Sheet1 between them.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

hypPath = ("C:\\dirTest\\hyperionDIR\\")
cogPath = ("C:\\dirTest\\cognosDIR\\")
hypFiles = os.listdir(hypPath)
cogFiles = os.listdir(cogPath)

for hypFilename in hypFiles:
    for cogFilename in cogFiles:
        if cogFilename == hypFilename:
            # print("file: " + cogFilename + " has a pair!")

        hypDf = pd.ExcelFile(hypPath + hypFilename)
        cogDf = pd.ExcelFile(cogPath + cogFilename)
        hypDf = hypDf.parse(0)
        cogDf = cogDf.parse(0)

        if hypDf.size >= cogDf.size:
            diffFile = hypDf.copy()
            cogDf = cogDf.align(hypDf,axis = None)
        else:
            diffFile = cogDf.copy()
            hypDf = hypDf.align(cogDf,axis = None)

        for row in range(diffFile.shape[0]):
            for col in range(diffFile.shape[1]):
                value_OLD = hypDf.iat[row, col]
                value_NEW = cogDf.iat[row, col]
                if value_OLD == value_NEW:
                    diffFile.iat[row, col] = cogDf.iat[row, col]
                else:
                    diffFile.iat[row, col] = ('{}→{}').format(value_OLD, value_NEW)
```

for value_NEW = cogDf.iat[row, col]
code throws:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iat'

I was trying to use iat attribute to then iterate through each cell in the dataframe and compare the differences between two sheets. That's why I was thinking to convert tuple (that I get from using .align) to dataframe to then be able to compare dataframes on .iat

The desired output could be pretty much the same as it is in this tutorial: https://matthewkudija.com/blog/2018/07/21/excel-diff/

Ideally, I'd also like to treat column names as part of the dataframe (in comparison, I also sometimes get column naming differences but data in columns are the same sets between two excel files)

Comment: `small, _ = df_small.align(df_large); print(small)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coldspeed is correct you can use `align`.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"x": [123, 123, 123],
        "y": [123, 123, 123],
        'z': [123, 123, 123]}

data2 = {"x": [123, 123, 123],
        "y": [123, 123, 123]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, axis = None)

print(df1)
print(df2)

     x    y    z
0  123  123  123
1  123  123  123
2  123  123  123
     x    y   z
0  123  123 NaN
1  123  123 NaN
2  123  123 NaN
```

This should work for the second part of your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

hypPath = ("C:\\dirTest\\hyperionDIR\\")
cogPath = ("C:\\dirTest\\cognosDIR\\")

hypFiles = os.listdir(hypPath)
cogFiles = os.listdir(cogPath)

for hypFilename in hypFiles:
    for cogFilename in cogFiles:
        if cogFilename == hypFilename:
            #print("file: " + cogFilename + " has a pair!")
            hypDf = pd.ExcelFile(hypPath + hypFilename)
            cogDf = pd.ExcelFile(cogPath + cogFilename)
            hypDf = hypDf.parse(0)
            cogDf = cogDf.parse(0)
        if hypDf.size >= cogDf.size:
            diffFile = hypDf.copy()
            cogDf, hypDf = cogDf.align(hypDf,axis = None)
        else:
            diffFile = cogDf.copy()
            hypDf, cogDf = hypDf.align(cogDf,axis = None)

type(hypDf)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(cogDf)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: It seems like align converts dataframe to tuple? I need this aligned dataframe for further comparison using iat. Can I convert tuple to dataframe somehow?

Comment: Can you show me the code you are currently working with and the desired output?

Comment: I say this because if df1 is a dataframe then df2 should be modified into a dataframe as well so I suspect there is an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've added the code to my initial question.

Comment: Try changing _cogDf = cogDf.align(hypDf,axis = None)_ to **cogDf, hypDf = cogDf.align(hypDf,axis = None)** and _hypDf = hypDf.align(cogDf,axis = None)_ to **hypDf, cogDf = hypDf.align(cogDf,axis = None)**. That should ensure both are dataframes and not tuples.

Comment: So basically what I needed to do was to do align on both files I'm comparing and align it to the larger one? I'm assuming 'cogDf, hypDf' syntax treats both dataframes.

Comment: What's interesting - it still treats NaN pairs as different. I wonder if there's a way I can also treat null cells as the same?

Comment: That is unfortunate to hear, you should consider asking another question if all else fails while trying to fix this new issue. I believe this question has been fully addressed. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.